# Why is 'identified by' mandatory in some grant commands?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-administration, sql-grant

I don't understand this.  I have a database, `my_database`, and a table, `tablename`.  I have a user, `ken` who has read only access to the database.  This user is already set up with a password, and people use this username remotely.  I want to give them some permissions on `tablename`.

This doesn't work:

```
mysql> grant SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE on my_database.tablename to 'ken'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

But this does:

```
mysql> grant SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE on my_database.tablename to 'ken'@'%' identified by password '<existing password hash>';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Why? I thought the `identified by` part was optional if they're already a user?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why would you do something so confusing as grant the ability to `INSERT`, `UPDATE`,  and `DELETE` to a user you've named `read_only` (which seems to indicate they're only allowed to read (`SELECT`) from the data? That seems like a really poorly thought out idea to me.

Comment: Because that's not the real username.

Comment: Hmm.. OK. I personally would have gone with "I have a user, Joe, who...". :-)

Comment: There you go.  Changed it for you.

Comment: Thanks. Let me know when my rights change goes through, will you? :-)

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this behaviour on a clean database on the same server? What does `SHOW GRANTS FOR ken@'%'` give you before and after the GRANT statement without password?

Comment: I'm beginning to think this was some sort of replication issue.  I think I'll close this question.

Comment: You might as well delete it. Just wasted 5 minutes, not reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely a MySQL replication issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can restrict the `GRANT` statement to the user only if it has logged on by this specific authentication method (here: password). This is at least the case with the `CREATE USER` statement, and I think it should be similar here...

For details, please search for `auth_option` on [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html) page.